# How to try Dagger 2 with pure java Project using Maven - intellij IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dagger

i heard Dagger 2 from a friend use it in Android. it pretty good!

But i have a crazy idea, i want to try Dagger 2 example in a pure java project build in Maven and use intellij IDEA. But something wrong by Compiler couldn't generate DaggerCoffeeShop class from ConffeeShop Interface like Dagger user guide.

All my example code same as example.

```
CoffeeShop coffeeShop = DaggerCoffeeShop.builder()
    .dripCoffeeModule(new DripCoffeeModule())
    .build();
```

I tried with turn on `enable annotation processing` in `setting` > `compiler` but it not work. I need your help to complete my crazy idea.  :(

Comment: It is not a crazy idea. Dagger2 can and is used in Java. Make sure you have imported the library correctly in maven/gradle (or in your classpath if you are not using maven/gradle)

Comment: I declare dependency  in pom.xml with below code and i can use Dagger2 annotation normally. Just only generate DaggerCoffeShop class from CoffeShop interface can not be done. 


`<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>`

Comment: I didn't manage to make it work also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use JDK 8. It should support JDK 9, but I did not figure it out how to do it ;)

Be sure to include in POM:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
        <version>2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>2.11</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                        <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>2.11</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: for anyone facing issues, make sure that all dependencies are there. For me i was missing the ``` <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>2.11</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>```

Answer (score 3):

In Intelij Dagger2 creates auto generated classes under dir target\generated-sources. You will have to add this folder to your source and you will able to use these auto generated java classes.